# How to check LocalDateTime instance is local or UTC in java?

Tags: java, utc, java-time, localdate

I have want to find whether my `LocalDateTime` instance holds local date&time or UTC date&time (like `DateTime.Kind` property in C#)

```
LocalDateTime date1=LocalDateTime.now(); // it is local

LocalDateTime date2=LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")); // it is UTC
```

Anything like `(date1.getKind() == Kind.UTC || date1.getKind() == Kind.Local)` in Java?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible, the javadoc says "This class does not store or represent a time-zone" .

Comment: My not so solid understanding was, that `ZonedDateTime` is for a separate accompaning zone, and `LocalDateTime` has no internal notion of zone. One can get a ZonedDateTime from a LocalDateTime with `atZone(...)`.

Comment: You could/should use ZonedDateTime. You can alsp retrieve a ZonedDateTime from your LocalDateTime. `LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(); ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));` and in ZonedDateTime you can access zoneId.

Comment: @Naxos84 ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")); this statement convert the LocalDateTime to UTC time but my initial LocalDateTime was local. From this how can I find the zone information?? zdt will always return UTC right?

Comment: You could use `ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now()` so the ZoneId will be `ZoneId.systemDefault()`

Comment: @Naxos84 I will get LocalDateTime from my user and it cannot be modified. So that only I'm requiring to find the zone info from LocalDateTime instance.

Comment: Ok I understand. Well as @Berger stated: LocalDateTime does not store a ZoneId even though it is created with one. This absolutely makes sense to me, cause it is "local" ;)

Comment: @sarathkumar If you want the zone info, then you must use a `ZonedDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime` simply doesn't have this information (if you can't change this type, then the zone should be stored in a separate field). That's the difference between the 2 languages: in C#, the `DateTime` class has a property saying if it's local or UTC. In Java, there's a different **class** to represent each one (just 2 different ways to solve the same problem, IMO, so you must change your mindset and adapt your code accordingly).

Answer (score 8):

The `LocalDateTime` object itself doesn't store the timezone information - it has only the date and time related fields: day, month and year; hour, minute, seconds and nanoseconds. But the `now` method uses a timezone or an offset to get the correct values for those fields.

That's because the answer to the questions *"What day is today?"* and *"What time is it?"* is not as simple as we might think.

It's common to think that the answer is as simple as taking a look at our calendar/cell phone/whatever and seeing the current date/time. But the technically correct answer is: *"It depends"*.

It depends, basically, on **where you are**. At this moment, each place in the world has its own local date and time. For example, in **July 5<sup>th</sup>, 2017**: while it was 14h (or 2 PM) in São Paulo, it was 6 PM in London and 5 PM in UTC, but in Tokyo it was 2 AM of **the next day (July 6<sup>th</sup>)**.

Each region in the world has specific rules to determine what's their local time during history, and of course it affects their local date.
And the concept that maps a country/city/region to these rules is a **timezone**.

That's why the `now` method needs a timezone. The `ZoneId` object loads all the timezone data to check what's the current date and time in that zone and adjust the day/month/year/hour/minute/second/nanosecond values accordingly. The version that receives no parameters (`LocalDateTime.now()`) will use the system's default timezone, so the API always uses some timezone in the end.

The timezone (or the offset, such as `ZoneOffset.UTC`) is used to get the correct values for day, month, year, hour, minute, second and nanosecond, and then - in the case of `LocalDateTime` and any other classes that don't keep the zone - discarded.

So, the concept might be a little different from what you're thinking. If I do:

```
// ZoneOffset.UTC is equivalent to ZoneId.of("UTC")
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

What this code does is: *"take the current date and time in UTC, and get just the date and time fields, discarding the timezone/offset information"*.

When I ran this code, the current date/time in UTC was `2017-09-25T12:15:43.570Z`, so the `LocalDateTime` has the value equivalent to `2017-09-25T12:15:43.570` (without any timezone information, just the date and time fields). If I call `now()` without arguments, it'll use the JVM default timezone (in my case, it's `America/Sao_Paulo`), and the value will be `2017-09-25T09:15:43.570`.

So, with a `LocalDateTime` you can get the values, **but you can't know from which timezone those values came from**, because it doesn't keep this information.

If you want a UTC date, you must use another classes, designed to keep this information:

- `Instant.now()` - this will always get the current UTC instant
- `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` - with this you can query for date and time fields (such as `getDayOfMonth()` or `getHour()`)
- `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` - for UTC, it's the same as `OffsetDateTime`, but if you use a different timezone, it handles all timezone specific data, such as Daylight Saving Time changes.

To check if such object is in UTC, one way is to use the `getZone()` method:

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(z.getZone().equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // true
```

But if you use equivalents like `ZoneId.of("UTC")`, the `equals` method return `false`. So you could also check if `z.getZone().getId()` is equals to `Z` or `UTC`. With `OffsetDateTime`, it's similar:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(odt.getOffset().equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // true
```

With `Instant` you don't need to check, because it's always in UTC.

You can check all the available types in [Oracle's date/time tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html).

---

Both `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` can be converted to a `LocalDateTime` using the `toLocalDateTime()` method:

```
// dt will have the current date and time in UTC
LocalDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();

// or
LocalDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
```

With this, the `dt` variable will have all the date and time fields (day/month/year, hour/minute/second/nanosecond) that corresponds to the current date/time in UTC. But it won't keep any timezone/offset information, so the `LocalDateTime` object itself can't know from which timezone those values came from.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old, but I am learning Java and found myself trying to do something very similar. After some reading I found I could do what you are asking with this:

```
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone()); // The clock argument is not really needed here.

    String pattern = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Setup your format for output
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    System.out.println("Local time is: " + dtf.format(now));

    LocalDateTime utc = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()); // Define alternate timezone
    System.out.println("GMT/UTC is: "+dtf.format(utc));
}
```